# Dynamic Record Generation in Table. Not displaying data properly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code in which data from a database's table is displayed in a table. But after 2-3 records, it is not displaying records properly.

This is the code:

```
<tr>
      <?php do { ?>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['notification']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['online_date']; ?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

It generates the following output:
[image: My 3rs record's notification is empty, and 4th record is not displaying properly.]

Row HTML Output is:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="900" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="5"><div align="center">Active Notifications </div></td>
      <td rowspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No.</td>
      <td>Notifications</td>
      <td>Online Date </td>
      <td colspan="2">Transactions</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Our New destinations are Countries.</td>
        <td>2012-12-27</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>abcdefgh</td>
        <td>2012-12-27</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Hi</td>
        <td>2012-12-27</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>2012-12-27</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
      <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

your `<tr>` tag is outside of the loop, while the closing one is inside.

Comment: I have tried putting <tr> tag within do while, but it is still not working.

Comment: Can you supply us with the raw HTML output?

Comment: The html of the generated table.

Comment: It's hard to tell since the added html output does not match with your screenshot. Grasping at straws here, but try changing the appropriate line to this: <?php echo (isnull($row_Recordset1['notification'] ? "&nbsp" : $row_Recordset1['notification']); ?>

Comment: user984444, I have tried this by eplacing your code: <?php echo (isnull($row_Recordset1['notification']) ? "&nbsp" : $row_Recordset1['notification']); ?>. But it is still not working...

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm thinking your loop should be a plain `while` loop instead of a `do ... while`, unless you have some code earlier on that is getting the first record.

Second, your `<tr>` tag was outside the loop and it should be inside it:

```
  <?php while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['notification']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['online_date']; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not being displayed correctly? from html point of view or data point of view? If from html point of view, you are opening the tr outside the loop, however you are closing it inside the loop. Basicly your structure would look like: `tr td td td td /tr td td td td /tr` instead of `tr td td td td /tr tr td td td td \tr`

Comment: It's about html point of view and I tried putting <tr> tag inside but still it's not working.